# Check if a function return is in an interval

Tags: bash

I have a function that can return different values:

```
function create_node() {
if ...
  return 1
elif...
   return 3
else ...
 return 4
}
```

How do I check if a return value is in an interval

```
create_node
if [[ $? is from 1 to 6 included ]]; then
```

Comment: A function cannot have more than 1 return statement

Comment: @Inian, is a conditional return, not all are return at the same time

Comment: Check if min of range is <= result and max of range is >= result.  I dont know bash syntax, but something like if [[1 <= $? && 6 >= $?

Comment: @user3541631: Use `$?` in place of the variables in the duplicated question. Or simply just `if [ "$?" -ge 1 -a "$?" -le 6 ]; then`